# Thread safety within Java

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

So, while working on something that was having locking issues, a question came to me. Do objects that only can be accessed from a single thread require locks or synchronization at all?

For example, given Thread1, Thread2, and Thread3, along with Buffer1, Buffer2, Buffer3, where each buffer is instanced as a thread is created, meaning that Thread1 will only ever access Buffer1, and the same for Thread2 and Buffer2, along with Thread3 and Buffer3. Thread1 will never touch Buffer2 or Buffer3. While adding/removing/modifying bytes in the stream, are locks needed?

Comment: +1 for a thought provoker :D - My answer is no.  Synchronization (as I understand) ensures that only one thread may access a shared resource at a time.  So as you describe it, then no...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** When **more than one thread try to access an object, then locking becomes necessary.**

**2.** Moreover classes when developed needs to be thread safe, **if concurrent access by threads is possible.**

**3.** A class is said to be thread safe, it if behaves correctly in the presence of interleaving and scheduling of the underlying OS , without any synchronization mechanism from the client.

**4. Locking the resources** can cause **overhead, prevents concurrent access, and bottle neck situations.**

Answer (score 2):

No, You wont need any locks in this case. Locking and synchronization is only required when any resource is being shared between multiple threads.

If you go ahead and add synchronization on the private instance of that buffer then still it wont make any difference as there will be no thread waiting to acquire locks, The only one locking and releasing the buffer will be the owner thread.

Answer (score 1):

Only when two or more threads need to access a shared object you need to worry about locking.

Comment: Alright. That's what I was thinking, but since the objects I'm working at are the core of the program, I wanted to be dead positive that I can go without locking or synchronization.

Answer (score 1):

No. This strategy for ensuring thread-safety is generally referred to as confinement.

Confinement relies on encapsulation techniques to ensure that multiple threads cannot access an object. "Concurrent Programming in Java" by Doug Lea has good chapter on the details of confinement and its strengths and weaknesses compared to other exclusion techniques.

Paraphrasing from Lea, in general there are 4 conditions needed for confinement of a reference r, to an object x, within a method m:

1. m cannot pass r as an argument to another method.
2. m cannot pass r as a return value.
3. m cannot record r in a field (instance or static) that is accessible from another thread.
4. m cannot may not let any other references escape (via 1-3) that may be traversed to r.

Answer (score 0):

From what I remember from my studies, if you are using a private buffer for every thread you should not worry about locking it to avoid concurrent access, since you don't have any.

If no-one is reading the buffer apart from the creator, it could do whatever he wants on it without worrying that someone else is reading or writing it. so you should be fine

But you have to remember that a thread can be interrupted at any time, so your internal buffer can be in a inconsistent state. (this shouldn't be a problem since you are accessing only sequentially from the same thread)

Answer (score 0):

Locks are not needed unless threads are concurrently using the same data structure.

Hence if different data structures are used by each thread, your code is guaranteed to be thread safe.

Incidentally, this is one of the main reasons why the key Java collection classes like `java.util.ArrayList` are *not* thread safe: making them thread safe would add a performance overhead which you shouldn't have to pay for if you don't need, and in a lot of cases you don't need it because you can ensure in some other way that only one thread accesses the ArrayList at once.